# Talend Use parameters in tmap expression

Tags: java, etl, talend

Is there a way to assign parameters (global/context) in the expression filter of a tmap in talend?

I know we can use the context.par_name in expression filter but my use case is: I have a tmap with one input table and output table. In the output table, the filter condition is defined row1.col-name == null.

What I will be getting here is a list of columns from the input table on which this check needs to be performed.

I tried using row1.context.col-name (column name is coming from parameters) but it is giving me error.

Comment: could take a capture of your tmap ?

Comment: Perhaps you could take advantage of tDBColumnList component ? I have no precise answer to give, but this component could help you get the list of column names from your Table.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs , i have resolved the issue by using Java reflection class to get the dynamic columns based on passed parameters at runtime